# What is the difference between Exchange & Offer in the Monetary System for NXT / Ardor Platform?

Tags: nxt, ardor, ignis, nxt-monetary-system

When creating a new monetary system coin on the NXT/Ardor platform. What is the difference from **Exchange** and **Offer**?

What does the following mean in the Exchange Window?

- Minimum Rate
- Effective Rate

What do the following mean in the Offer window?

- Buy units (Initial)
- Buy units (Limit)
- Buy Rate per unit
- Sell units (Initial)
- Sell units (Limit)
- Sell Rate per unit

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to the official monetary system documentation https://bitbucket.org/JeanLucPicard/nxt/issues/205/monetary-system-documenation section "Currency Exchange".
The NXT wiki also has an excellent walk-through of the process in https://nxtwiki.org/wiki/Monetary_System#Exchange_an_Exchangeable_Currency